# code adds one item to listview and then stops

Tags: android

I have the following code that is a dynamic listview where you type in the textbox and click the add button and its added to the listview below. Listview is a custom listview with 2 textviews. Somehow the code adds the first item and then does not add the rest. The arraylist gets the item, i call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and yet still the listview does not get updated. What am i doing wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ManageComplaintsActivity extends DashboardActivity {




    EditText txtAddComplaint;
    ListView lvComplaintsList;
    Button btnAddComplaint;
    private SimpleAdapter adapter;
    private int count = 1;
    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_complaints);
        setTitleFromActivityLabel (R.id.title_text);


        txtAddComplaint= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddComplaint);
        lvComplaintsList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvComplaintsList);
        btnAddComplaint = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddComplaint);

        String[] from = { "complaint", "complaintid" };
        int[] to = { R.id.lblC, R.id.lblCID };
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter (this, list, R.layout.activity_manage_complaints_row, from, to);

        lvComplaintsList.setAdapter(adapter);

        btnAddComplaint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item.put("complaint", txtAddComplaint.getText().toString());
                item.put("complaintid", Integer.toString(count));
                list.add(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                count++;
                txtAddComplaint.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(list.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        lvComplaintsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){      
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblC)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }           
        });        
    }
}
```

This is the 2 xml files

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:shrinkColumns="1"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtAddComplaint"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAddComplaint"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Add" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtComplaintLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="List of Complaints : "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lvComplaintsList"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_span="2" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the listviewrow xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have also tried  lvComplaintsList.invalidateViews() after calling   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and it still does not refresh the listview. Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the main xml file as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtAddComplaint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddComplaint"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add to Listview" >
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView

             android:id="@+id/lvComplaintsList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I had used a table layout and the listview was in one of the rows.
Hope this helps someone .

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in documentation to [SimppleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) it is

> An easy adapter to map **static data** to views defined in an XML file.

I believe that you can find any tricky way to add data dynamically. But I'm not sure that you have to do it like this. Try to use [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) instead. By default it binds T.toString() values to single TextView, but you can override getView(int, View, ViewGroup) to return the type of view you want.

Comment: Hi @olegr the simpleAdapter is working somehow. I had to change the main xml as the listview was in a tablerow. I will post the code tomorrow morning as i have to wait 8hrs to post an answer. Thanks for your help.